# Are there any ways to sync open chrome tabs from android to ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, android, sync

I am syncing my google account on android and ubuntu. Now I can see history, bookmarks and open tabs. But the open tabs works in one direction. I can see open tabs from ubuntu on android but cannot otherwise. I google some manuals and they all says that there is must be "other device" at the bottom of the new tab or "recent tabs" button, but I have not.

Comment: I think it is question to ask the Google developers.

Comment: I can see all my devices in the recent tabs on all my devices.

Answer (score 0):

This "other devices" button can be found on the history page, in the left panel.

However, I'm pretty much positive this is not Ubuntu related.